# vnstat output giving different results

Tags: linux, linux-networking

I ran vnstat -d and vnstat -m and compared the results to vnstat --dump.

The values between daily and monthly are off by several bytes. Is this expected? I would imagine last months data and yesterday's data wouldn't be changing as its not logging for those times.

For example, on the monthly output I have from vnstat -m  (rx/tx format)

```
27.21 | 7.96
```

and on vnstat --dump

```
27.214 | 7.982
```

I can see vnstat --m rounding down on the rx since the numbers are close, but I don't understand the tx discrepancy.

Any idea what's going on here?